# Jquery Ajax paging Next/Prev -- dynamic data

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination

I am new to ajax and also jquery. I am building a search page and that needs to be paged since it will have many records. I found many tutorials where we can do that. But all one which I saw has page numbers on it. I mean if we have like 9 pages,

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...

I may not need something like this but I need like first prev next last and if by chance I can give them a field to enter page number(optional).

I am using php mysql and limit to achieve this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could look into using an inline frame and simply loading your search page into it.  Thats far more easy...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you send your serach request with ajax and have a JSON object returned with a list containing the search hits and some metadata about the search (such as *total_hits* that states how many hits there are available on the server. This number should be equal or greater than the length of *hitlist*).

```
GET /search?q=<query>

{'hitlist': [...],
 'total_hits': 1234}
```

The size of the hit-list could be ~3 pages since this is probably the most common hits that the user will see. So for the three first pages you don't need to access the server. This could be done in jQuery on the browser. For more results you could have your server support an optional parameter such as:

```
GET /search?q=<query>&limit=20,40
```

The *limit* syntax could be the same MySQL's, then you could ask for the 10 last too (just remember to take proper precautions when passing those parameters into your database if you use SQL!)

So for the pagination look on the browser you could determine how it should look like from the *total_hits* value. If there are few you don't need pagination and if there are super many you could settle with just a *next* button. All results could be showed in a  and if you want any fancy pagination effects you could take a look at http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/ .